# SaveChanges() doesn't work (Entity Framework, C#, Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I have a very weird problem. I try to submit changes to the database (using Entity Framework)
like this:

```
private ProfEntities pe = new ProfEntities();
//...
var row = pe.Irregular_Veebs.Single(e => e.id == id); //selecting one row by id
row.seen = true; //changing seen property to true
pe.SaveChanges();
```

it looks simple but it doesn't work: when I look in Database Explorer, the "seen" field is still false. AM I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you refresh the view in data explorer?

Comment: if you're using file database you'll have to open database from debug or release folder

Comment: Don't you need to call some sort of update method before SaveChanges() ?

Comment: @wiero - suggest you make this a proper "answer" so OP can upvote you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using file database you probably explore db which is in your solution folder. To see changes you should open db from Release or Debug folder